# Force-utilizing multiple cores

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing

So I have an executable which I need to run a number of times with different input parameters. It takes around an hour per run, and I've noticed during the entire hour CPU utilisation of only 1 core out of 8 is at 100%, rest of them are idling.

Is it possible to spawn 4-5 processes, each using a different core and working on different parameters? Is this common practice? This is the first time I'm bothering about multiple cores so if there are any other things I need to be aware of please let me know.

Currently I'm using Python to run and wait for this executable to finish.

Comment: Depends on if the resources are sharable or not. If they have a common external source, it may be difficult, but its difficult to say without more information.

Comment: You should give a try with the `multiprocessing` module (**NOT** threading for CPU bound processes because of the Python Global Interpretor Lock)

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is routinely done when compiling big programs - multiple compiler processes are spawned, working on different files.

If your program is CPU bound as it seems, the input data is easily partitionable and the various instances wouldn't stomp on each other's feet when writing the results, you can try and see if you obtain the expected speedup.

Answer (score 1):

When running parallel processes shared resources should be taken into consideration, plus depending on load profile it may or may not be faster than single process(for example if bottleneck is not the cpu)

Common problems are usually related to "race conditions" and deadlocks, former is the case when two processes work with same data not knowing about each other so that data gets corrupted due to overwrites for example

Not knowing more details about the task it's impossible to answer exactly

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this, as has already been suggested, was to partition your input set in the application and process it in parallel using the multiprocessing module.

Alternatively you can partition the input up-front and run multiple copies of your program on the inputs using GNU parallel or good old xargs (look at -n and -P options).

Then there is the problem of merging the results back together, if needed.

All of this hinges on being able to split inputs into parts that can be processed independently, without coordination or shared memory. Otherwise it gets more complex.